# Application installed but 'stop repelatedly' on Android

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am using the third-party library sample application for flutter.

It works well on iPhone but on Android(real device).

Being installed correctly ,but show message "stops repeatedly"

Application doesn't launch.

I wonder it is the problem of my Android ,flutter version or sample itself....but there is no hint on my logs.

I don't even know where should I start

Do you think there is some hint in this log?

```
[   +4 ms] Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/wikitude-flutter-plugin-examples-master/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/wikitude-flutter-plugin-examples-master/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="10" (Raw: "10")
               A: package="com.wikitude.fluttersamples" (Raw: "com.wikitude.fluttersamples")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: platformBuildVersionName="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.CAMERA" (Raw: "android.permission.CAMERA")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-feature (line=22)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=25)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.camera" (Raw: "android.hardware.camera")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=28)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.location" (Raw: "android.hardware.location")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=31)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=34)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.compass" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.compass")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
               E: uses-feature (line=37)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" (Raw: "android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope")
                 A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
               E: application (line=47)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="Flutter Examples" (Raw: "Flutter Examples")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=53)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x400037b4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=67)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=71)
                     E: action (line=72)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=74)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=78)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="optional" (Raw: "optional")
                 E: activity (line=82)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.architect.BrowserActivity" (Raw: "com.wikitude.architect.BrowserActivity")
                 E: activity (line=83)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.wikitude.tools.activities.MediaPlayerActivity" (Raw: "com.wikitude.tools.activities.MediaPlayerActivity")
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x4a0
                 E: activity (line=86)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=91)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060001
                 E: activity (line=94)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x103023a
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x4a0
                 E: meta-data (line=101)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version" (Raw: "com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0xac70498
[   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM G975F.
[        ] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell am force-stop com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[ +109 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell pm list packages com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[ +108 ms] package:com.wikitude.fluttersamples
[   +4 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.wikitude.fluttersamples.sha1
[  +41 ms] 5cbf84c4099fa8db25f788fba1afcbc8fde17b72
[        ] Latest build already installed.
[        ] SM G975F startApp
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s R58M20JNSQB shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez
enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.wikitude.fluttersamples/com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity
[ +106 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.wikitude.fluttersamples/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

If it is permission problem, `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` is like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wikitude.fluttersamples">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Flutter Examples"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.wikitude.fluttersamples.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you can please add the sample code you're using? Might be permission issue or something

Comment: https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-flutter-plugin-examples sample code is here.

Comment: `OMi Shah` thank you for hit, it it is permission problem, I put the AndroidManifest.xml in article.